# Как проверить возможность хода на шахматной доске?

Tags: java, алгоритм, ооп

Есть шахматная доска и 3 фигуры: ладья, слон и ферзь (как они двигаются, надеюсь, понятно).

Здесь необходимо реализовать метод проверки "возможен ли ход" так, чтобы было минимальное копирование кода. Метод принимает на вход объект координат (x,y) фигуры, может передвигаться неограниченное количество клеток.
Но! Здесь не надо реализовывать визуальное передвижение фигур, метод просто должен возвращать bool.
Я не прошу вас это сделать за меня. Мне нужен совет, как реализовывать метод проверки.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для ладьи допустимыми позициями будут те, в которых отличается только одна из координат.

Comment: Проверка ферзя сочетает в себе  проверку ладьи и слона, если я правильно понял смысл.

Comment: ну я вижу как двумерный массив 8 на 8 и проверять если не координата куда ходит фигура свободно и путь до этой координаты не занят то все ок

Comment: Раз уж это тест на ООП, то и делайте ООП: создайте классы "ладья", "слон", "ферзь". Создайте в них методы проверки хода. Оп, методы оказались похожи: названия и сигнатуры одинаковые. Значит, что? Нужно сделать базовый класс, в котором будет этот метод проверки (виртуальный!), а в потомках он переопределяется. Теперь можно перебирать коллекцию объектов фигур, вызывая этот метод. Полагаю, именно этого от вас ждут - как спроектировать иерархию классов, а не как реализовать конкретный метод.

Comment: Когда-то писал шахматы. Нужен метод Move[] validMoves(), возвращающий массив доступных ходов. Он будет для каждой фигуры свой. Ну и потом играемся этими массивами, смотрим их пересечения итд. Также советую почитать про pgn notation - универсальный метод описания таких игр как шахматы, шашки...

Answer (score 3):

Окей начнем с ООП. Я просто опишу архитектуру как бы делал я тебе понадобиться:

Интерфейс : Фигура с набором методов (Тут сам решай но я бы туда добавил метод ход - описание алгоритма хода для фигуры, гетеры и сетеры для места расположения фигуры один для x второй для y, гетЛагерьФигуры - белые черныеб ХешКод)

Классы имплементирующие интерфейс Фигура: Ладья, Слон, Ферзь

Класс: Доска которая под капотом имеет в себе бинарный массив где 1 это место занятое фигурой, 0 свободное место. А так же список ссылок на все фигуры которые находятья на доске. Хотя лучше два списка один для черных второй для белых.  Даже наверное можно было бы подумать о мапе [хеш] ссылка на фигуру.

Таким образом ты демонстрируещь: инкапсуляцию, полиморфизм, абстракцию. Ну наследование  здесь в виде интерфейса.

Answer (score 0):

Ладья:

```
public boolean canmove(final int x, final int y) {
    return y == Y && x != X || y != Y && x == X;
}
```

Слон:

```
public boolean canmove(final int x, final int y) {
    return (x - y) == (X - Y) || (x + y) == (X + Y);
}
```

Ферзь:

```
public boolean canmove(final int x, final int y) {
    return y == Y && x != X || y != Y && x == X || (x - y) == (X - Y) || (x + y) == (X + Y);
}
```

Comment: А вы случайно ладью с королем не перепутали? И ваши вычисления подходят для пустой доски, без фигур, которые могут быть на пути.

Comment: @VladD, дак он и просил только проверку.

Comment: Окей, а почему `(x > (X) || (x < (X))`, а не просто `(x != X)`?

Comment: @VladD, дело в том, что я, давно это делал. Поправил ответ, убрал лишнее.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ @Ihor Bondartcov.

Я бы добавил общий класс фигура и отнаследовал от него фигуры Ладья, Слон, Ферзь.

По поводу Вашего вопроса о методике:

каждый ход это пара чисел (так считать удобнее - сделайте сопоставление A-0, ... H-7 или A-1, ... H-8 )

1. Ладья

Как Вам уже подсказали в коментариях (@Владимир Мартьянов): ладья - это проверка, что изменилась только 1 координата.

2. Слон

Слон - это проверка, что координаты поменялись синхронно, т.е. если это было +n к Х то и +n к Y. (ц - целое)

3. Ферзь (как писал @Lyth) - это проверка типа (уловие.Слон или условие.Ладья)

Плюс ко всем проверкам обязательная проверка отсутствия на пути препятствий.