# Пройти с for по двумерному массиву

Tags: java, массивы

Вопрос такой, дана задача на 8 ферзей и метод

```
public static boolean reschenie(boolean[][] pole)
```

В общем, этот метод описывает поле n на n и, если оно 8 на 8, то там будут размещены 8 ферзей, и если они не будут "бить" друг друга, то метод будет возвращать true иначе false (если хоть один может быть побит другим ферзем).

Можно работать с for оператором и другими простыми операторами, но не с готовыми алгоритмами (поэтому я и выбрал for чтобы пройти им по массиву).

Вопрос - как можно проверить двумерный массив?

P.S. Я понимаю как пройти for по одномерному массиву, но как это сделать с двумерным массивом в методе?

Подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: Один вариант - внутри первого for применить вложенный for по второму индексу. Другой - представить двумерный массив в виде одномерного и использовать один for

Comment: Это не двумерный массив. Это зубчатый массив, или массив массивов. Если Вы знаете, как пройти по обычному массиву, получая на каждой итерации его элемент, то эта задача не сложнее: просто на каждой итерации получаемый элемент сам является массивом, так что мы можем пройтись по нему самому с помощью вложенного for.

Comment: Как это примерно будет выглядеть в реализации? Чтобы представление хотя бы иметь как оно делается..любой пример можно

Comment: Может поможет: [Возможность хода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737014/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5/737042#737042)

Comment: @And я думаю, что это следует поместить в ответ. Нужно сформировать два массива с координатами ладей, затем просто проверить двумя массивами (итератор второго равен итератору первого + 1) с помощью той ф-ции.

Comment: @Miron, я вообще не понимаю, что ему нужно, понял, что только нужно проверить ферзевый ход. Остальное как в темный лес смотрю....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так в двух циклах можно перебрать двумерный массив:

```
// Создаем и инициализируем двумерный массив (массив массивов)
int[][] arr = new int[3][];
arr[0] = new int[]{45, 65, 82, 12};
arr[1] = new int[]{43, 90, 44};
arr[2] = new int[]{21, 89, 22, 18, 57};

// проходим по всему массиву двумя циклами for
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j]; // здесь делаем с текущим элементом массива все, что нужно
    }
}
```

Или ридонли через форычи:

```
for (int[] ints : arr) {
    for (int anInt : ints) {
        anInt; // здесь делаем с текущим элементом массива все, что нужно (read only)
    }
}
```

Инициализировать массив тоже можно через такие циклы. Я здесь просто для наглядности показала, что двумерный массив может быть с разной длиной строк.